# Regular expression for accent mark and other characters

Tags: javascript

I need to validate if in a string exist any letter with accent mark or the Spanish letter `Ñ`. I tried using regular expression but, I can't find a solution.

this is my code:

```
var videoname = document.getElementById('url').value;
var BLIDRegExpression = /[Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\-\Ñ\ñ]+$/(]+$/;
var matchesCount = videoname.split(BLIDRegExpression).length - 1;
alert(matchesCount);
```

The alert shows `0` result.

Comment: Looks like you've copy/pasted some extra control characters into your regex. Doesn't look valid.

Comment: What is that `+$/(]+$` part supposed to do? Looks like a syntax error.

Comment: Remove the `(]+$/`  at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hasAccentChars = /^[a-z \u00E0-\u00FC]+$/i;
var str = "el niño";
console.log(hasAccentChars.test(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to test alphanumeric in portuguese. I think it fits spanish too. Take a look:

```js
var isAlphanumeric = (str) => /^[A-zÀ-ÿ0-9\–\-_\s\.\(\)\/]+$/.test( str );
console.log(isAlphanumeric('España'));
console.log(isAlphanumeric('España%&*'));
```

With a small change it does what you want:

```js
var hasAccent = (str) => /[À-ÿ]/.test( str );
console.log(hasAccent('España'));
console.log(hasAccent('Brasil'));
```